# Decoding jwt token

Tags: reactjs, jwt, decode

Im trying to decode my jwt token that im receiving when im logging in, but it returns ''null'' in the console.log.

This is the code where im decoding:

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

    function loginRequest(){
        const token = axios.post('https://afe2021fitness.azurewebsites.net/api/Users/login', 
        state).then(data => {localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', data.data.jwt);
        console.log(data.data.jwt)});

        console.log(jwt.decode(token));
    }
```

And i have also tried the decoder from the jwt-decode library without any luck:

```
var decoded = jwtdecode(token);
```

with this it says ''Uncaught (in promise) n {message: 'Invalid token specified'}''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the `console.log(jwt.decode(token))` inside the `then` block or use an `async` function:

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

async function loginRequest() {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.post(
      'https://afe2021fitness.azurewebsites.net/api/Users/login',
      state
    );
    const token = data.jwt;
    localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', token);
    console.log(token);

    console.log(jwt.decode(token));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you tried to use `token` variable before you initialized it. You also needed to use `await` before `Promise` returned from `axios.post`. Now you have to use `await` before calling `loginRequest`. So the final code looks like this:

```js
import jsonwebtoken from "jsonwebtoken";

async function loginRequest() {
  const response = await axios.post("https://afe2021fitness.azurewebsites.net/api/Users/login", state)
  const { jwt } = response.data
  localStorage.setItem("jwtToken", jwt);
  console.log(jwt);
  console.log(jsonwebtoken.decode(jwt));
}
```